# git push returns remote: TERM environment variable not set

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu-10.04

For some reason whenever I do a git push it returns:

> remote: TERM environment variable not set.

I've added

```
export TERM=linux
```

to both `~/.bash` and `~/.bashrc` but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I was having similar problems with `rsync` last week but ended up giving up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add this on the **remote** host?  How about something more basic, such as `vt220`?

Comment: yep it's in ~/.bashrc on the remote host - but problem is all fixed now (see reply to post by Keith Thompson). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like, as the message implies, something on the remote system is complaining about `$TERM` not being set, so setting it locally wouldn't do any good.  Normally `git push` shouldn't depend on `$TERM`, either on the local system or on the remote server.

My best guess is that there's a hook somewhere that invokes a command that depends on `$TERM`.  It shouldn't do that.  Take a look at the configuration of the server to which you're `push`ing, or talk to someone who can.

(Incidentally, the string "environment variable not set" doesn't appear anywhere in the git sources.)

Comment: Ahh yep that is probably it - I'd written a custom shell script in the post-receive hook which I've now changed and it seems to be fixed! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you export? Check if you exported after setting the term.

Answer (score 0):

The message says:

**remote:** TERM environment variable not set.

Make sure you set it on the remote you are pushing it to.